# How to make game use https when played via facebook and http when played from other domain

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, https, facebook-canvas

Our users play our Django game directly via our domain, cnamed to herokuapp.com. We request our assets via http.

We want to add our game to facebook, which requires using https. Heroku can handle this.

Using https requests: our game works on facebook but fails to load assets when accessed via our cnamed domain.

Can we make our game use https when played via facebook and http when played from our domain? What code must we add to `settings.py`?

We've tried this code in `settings.py` but it didn't work

**Option 1:**

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname().startswith('app'):
  LIVEHOST = True
else:
  LIVEHOST = False

if LIVEHOST:
  STATIC_URL = "https://d******1.cloudfront.net/"
else:
  STATIC_URL = "http://d******1.cloudfront.net/"
```

**Option 2:**

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname().startswith('edge'):
  LIVEHOST = True
else:
  LIVEHOST = False

if LIVEHOST:
  STATIC_URL = "https://d******1.cloudfront.net/"
else:
  STATIC_URL = "http://d******1.cloudfront.net/"
```

Comment: can you not just use settings as `//d******1.cloudfront.net/` ?

Comment: karthik, the master of comment as answers. yes use protocol relative urls.

Comment: Don't know how didn't I tried this simple thing before. @karthikr post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`protocol relative urls`](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) to save yourself from the pain of worrying about the protocol to use.

So the settings would look like:

```
STATIC_URL = "//d******1.cloudfront.net/"
```

and you can safely get rid of all the computation logic in your code snippet.